# url 404 with I go in a specificy url

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, builder, ng-build

I have a web app and when I go on :

```
    http://localhost:8080/Test/home
http://localhost:8080/Test/login
```

It gives me 404, and it doesn't me the home

My `app-routing.ts` is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: environment.URL_LOGIN_ROUTING, loadChildren: () => import("./components/login/login.module").then(m =>
      m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: environment.URL_HOME_ROUTING, component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: environment.URL_LOGIN_ROUTING, pathMatch: 'full' }
  
];
```

in My `envinroment`  is:

```
//ROUTING
const URL_LOGIN_ROUTING = "/login";
const URL_HOME_ROUTING = "/home";
export const environment = {

  //DA INSERIRE NEL ROUTING
  URL_LOGIN_ROUTING: URL_LOGIN_ROUTING,
   URL_HOME_ROUTING: URL_HOME_ROUTING,

};
```

I start angular with:

```
ng build --watch --base-href /Test/
```

I I go on  `http://localhost:8080/Test/` it work but if I go on  `http://localhost:8080/Test/login` or

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/home
```

it gives me 404. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the preceeding `/` from your paths. You should never need a preceeding or a trailing `/` when dealing with angular `Router`.

```js
const URL_LOGIN_ROUTING = "login";
const URL_HOME_ROUTING = "home";
```